# Where does gcc look for C and C++ header files?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, header

On a Unix system, where does gcc look for header files?

I spent a little time this morning looking for some system header files, so I thought this would be good information to have here.

Comment: By the way, if you want to know where the .h file is location, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/18593344/1586797

Answer (score 265, accepted):

```
`gcc -print-prog-name=cc1plus` -v
```

This command asks gcc which **C++** preprocessor it is using, and then asks that preprocessor where it looks for includes.

You will get a reliable answer for your specific setup.

Likewise, for the **C** preprocessor:

```
`gcc -print-prog-name=cpp` -v
```

Comment: What do the `s mean? I'm finding it difficult to search for this.

Comment: @mijiturka [What does ` (backquote/backtick) mean in bash?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27428/what-does-backquote-backtick-mean-in-bash)

Comment: I guess the C **preprocessor** is `cpp` instead of `cc1`? On my debian jessie `$(gcc -print-prog-name=cpp) -v` (correctly) gives one more path, which is `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu`

Comment: If you want that to not hang waiting for input, redirect input from `/dev/null`, so `\`gcc -print-prog-name=cc1\` -v < /dev/null` .

Comment: @SteveJorgensen yep!  Or press `Ctrl`+`D`, which sends "end of file" in Unix-talk.

Comment: …but you can't press Ctrl+D from within a shell script.

Comment: This may give a misleading answer on operating systems where the "compiler driver" (the `gcc` or `g++` program) overrides the search paths compiled into the preprocessor.  For instance, on the computer I'm typing this, this recipe omits `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu` from the search path.

Comment: When I run "gcc -print-prog-name=cc1" it just outputs "cc1". No path at all. Seems the path is only printed if cc1 is found. I want to know the path where gcc is LOOKING for cc1. How can I do that?

Comment: I know that the backtick `` tells the shell to execute whatever is inside of it to be executed before the main command, but I do not understand what is the difference between:
`\`gcc -print-prog-name=cpp\` -v` 
and
`gcc -print-prog-name=cpp -v` 
or rather, _why_ are they different?

Answer (score 49):

In addition, gcc will look in the directories specified after the `-I` option.

Comment: @totaam: Check your font! This answer uses "-I" (capital "eye") not "-l" (lowercase "ell").

Comment: -I is for <anglebracketed.h> whereas -iquote is for "quotedfiles.h"

Answer (score 38):

You can create a file that attempts to include a bogus system header.
If you run gcc in verbose mode on such a source, it will list all the system include locations as it looks for the bogus header.

```
$ echo "#include <bogus.h>" > t.c; gcc -v t.c; rm t.c

[..]

#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin9/4.0.1/include
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.

[..]

t.c:1:32: error: bogus.h: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I think this would be more helpful if you just said "use the -v option".

Comment: Well if you use "-v" without a C file that includes a non-existent system header you will not cause gcc to iterate through all the include paths.
The key to my answer is bogus.h listed as a system header.

Comment: @Jay - you're right, it was too vague - I've explained what I was doing in the shell script.

Comment: @Jay:  The -v option by itself gives output that doesn't include system path.

Comment: without temporary files: `echo "#include <bogus.h>" | gcc -v -x c -`

Comment: `gcc -v -E - < /dev/null` or `cpp -v < /dev/null` are enough.  You just have to get the preprocessor to *run*, it doesn't matter what input it sees.  (The search paths are printed during startup, before it even looks at its input.)

Comment: @zwol Thanks for that, it's a lot more straight forward, and imho deserves to be a separate answer on its own.

Answer (score 20):

The [CPP Section](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.2/cpp/) of the [GCC Manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/index.html#dir) indicates that header files may be located in the following directories. From the [Search Path](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.2/cpp/Search-Path.html#Search-Path) page:

> GCC looks in several different places for headers. On a normal Unix system, if you do not instruct it otherwise, it will look for headers requested with #include  in:

```
 /usr/local/include
 libdir/gcc/target/version/include
 /usr/target/include
 /usr/include
```

> For C++ programs, it will also look in `/usr/include/g++-v3`, first.

Comment: That's fine for your current version of gcc. The actual directories it looks in depends on the options specified when gcc was built. See Shmoopty answer for a better solution.

Comment: PS: My C++ header files are in:  /usr/include/c++/4.0.0

Comment: @Martin:  You're old school.  Mine are in /usr/include/c++/4.2  :)

Comment: is this done recursively? i. e.  if i had a lib in `/usr/include/subdir/`, would it be picked up?

Comment: @Base64__ Yes, you can arrange header files in subdirectories under `/usr/include` and they will be found.

Answer (score 14):

To get GCC to print out the complete set of directories where it will look for system headers, invoke it like this:

```
$ LC_ALL=C gcc -v -E -xc - < /dev/null 2>&1 | 
  LC_ALL=C sed -ne '/starts here/,/End of/p'
```

which will produce output of the form

```
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
```

If you have `-I`-family options on the command line they will affect what is printed out.

(The `sed` command is to get rid of all the *other* junk this invocation prints, and the `LC_ALL=C` is to ensure that the `sed` command works -- the "starts here" and "End of search list" phrases *are* translated IIRC.)

Answer (score 12):

```
g++ -print-search-dirs
gcc -print-search-dirs
```

Comment: These commands print the default search paths for link libraries and internal components of the compiler; they don't tell you anything about header files.

Answer (score 9):

The set of paths where the compiler looks for the header files can be checked by the command:-

***cpp -v***

If you declare ***#include ""*** , the compiler first searches in current directory of source file and if not found, continues to search in the above retrieved directories.

If you declare ***#include <>*** , the compiler searches directly in those directories obtained from the above command.

Source:- http://commandlinefanatic.com/cgi-bin/showarticle.cgi?article=art026

Answer (score 1):

One could view the (additional) include path for a C program from bash by checking out the following:

```
echo $C_INCLUDE_PATH
```

If this is empty, it could be modified to add default include locations, by:

```
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=$C_INCLUDE_PATH:/usr/include
```

Comment: As you note it works for additional user specified directories, but it won’t work for the standard include paths, which is OP’s question.

Answer (score 1):

These are the directories that gcc looks in by default for the specified header files ( given that the header files are included in chevrons <>);
1. /usr/local/include/ --used for 3rd party header files.
2. /usr/include/ -- used for system header files.

If in case you decide to put your custom header file in a place other than the above mentioned directories, you can include them as follows:
1. using quotes ("./custom_header_files/foo.h") with files path, instead of chevrons in the include statement.
2. using the -I switch when compiling the code. 
gcc -I /home/user/custom_headers/ -c foo.c -p foo.o
Basically the -I switch tells the compiler to first look in the directory specified with the -I switch ( before it checks the standard directories).When using the -I switch the header files may be included using chevrons.

Answer (score 0):

My system has gcc9 by default and I have built a gcc12 from source and I think the accepted answer is not correct, that is `gcc -print-prog-name=cc1plus -v` doesn't give the real include search path.

My build configuration is

```
Configured with: /home/tian/playground/gcc_build_play/objdir/../gcc-12.1.0/configure --prefix=/home/tian/GCC-12.1.0 --disable-multilib
```

**And no matter where I `mv` the gcc12 directoy in my machine. It can always include its own c++ header files correctly.**

---

If I type `./gcc -print-prog-name=cc1plus -v`, in the original installed directory, it gives:

```
tian@tian-B250M-Wind:~/GCC-12.1.0/bin$ `./gcc -print-prog-name=cc1plus` -v
ignoring nonexistent directory "/home/tian/GCC-12.1.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /home/tian/GCC-12.1.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/../../../../include/c++/12.1.0
 /home/tian/GCC-12.1.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/../../../../include/c++/12.1.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
 /home/tian/GCC-12.1.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/../../../../include/c++/12.1.0/backward
 /home/tian/GCC-12.1.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/include
 /usr/local/include
 /home/tian/GCC-12.1.0/include
 /home/tian/GCC-12.1.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/include-fixed
 /usr/include
End of search list.
```

`mv` my gcc12 to `~/Desktop/`, run again, gives:

```
tian@tian-B250M-Wind:~/Desktop/GCC-12.1.0/bin$ `./gcc -print-prog-name=cc1plus` -v
ignoring nonexistent directory "/home/tian/GCC-12.1.0/include/c++/12.1.0"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/home/tian/GCC-12.1.0/include/c++/12.1.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/home/tian/GCC-12.1.0/include/c++/12.1.0/backward"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/home/tian/GCC-12.1.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/home/tian/GCC-12.1.0/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/home/tian/GCC-12.1.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/include-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/home/tian/GCC-12.1.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include
End of search list.
```

If that's true, then I compile a program with `./g++`, it should use c++ header files in `/usr/include` or `/usr/local/include`. But it's not.

Experiment is omitted here. You can try using `mv` to rename any header file of gcc12 your test program use or add some garbage code to the header file. Then you will see the gcc12 `./g++` is complaining about the gcc12 c++ header file, not my system gcc9's c++ header files in `/usr/include` or `/usr/local/include`.

So in both places `./g++` can find its gcc12 c++ headers files correctly.

---

So I guess `gcc` and `g++` are finding headers in relative directory, relative to `/path_to_gcc12/bin/gcc`.

Try`./g++ -g -Wall --verbose -o test test.cpp` gives the real include path:

```
tian@tian-B250M-Wind:~/Desktop/GCC-12.1.0/bin$ ./g++ -g -Wall --verbose -o test test.cpp
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=./g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/home/tian/Desktop/GCC-12.1.0/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: /home/tian/playground/gcc_build_play/objdir/../gcc-12.1.0/configure --prefix=/home/tian/GCC-12.1.0 --disable-multilib
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib
gcc version 12.1.0 (GCC) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-g' '-Wall' '-v' '-o' 'test' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /home/tian/Desktop/GCC-12.1.0/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/cc1plus -quiet -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu -iprefix /home/tian/Desktop/GCC-12.1.0/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/ -D_GNU_SOURCE test.cpp -quiet -dumpbase test.cpp -dumpbase-ext .cpp -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g -Wall -version -o /tmp/ccrg0qhG.s
GNU C++17 (GCC) version 12.1.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
        compiled by GNU C version 12.1.0, GMP version 6.2.1, MPFR version 4.1.0, MPC version 1.2.1, isl version isl-0.24-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/home/tian/Desktop/GCC-12.1.0/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/home/tian/Desktop/GCC-12.1.0/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/../../../../include/c++/12.1.0"
ignoring duplicate directory "/home/tian/Desktop/GCC-12.1.0/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/../../../../include/c++/12.1.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"
ignoring duplicate directory "/home/tian/Desktop/GCC-12.1.0/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/../../../../include/c++/12.1.0/backward"
ignoring duplicate directory "/home/tian/Desktop/GCC-12.1.0/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring duplicate directory "/home/tian/Desktop/GCC-12.1.0/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/include-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/home/tian/Desktop/GCC-12.1.0/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /home/tian/Desktop/GCC-12.1.0/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/../../../../include/c++/12.1.0
 /home/tian/Desktop/GCC-12.1.0/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/../../../../include/c++/12.1.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
 /home/tian/Desktop/GCC-12.1.0/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/../../../../include/c++/12.1.0/backward
 /home/tian/Desktop/GCC-12.1.0/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/include
 /home/tian/Desktop/GCC-12.1.0/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/include-fixed
 /usr/local/include
 /home/tian/Desktop/GCC-12.1.0/bin/../lib/gcc/../../include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
```

So I think my guess is correct.