# How to tell where a header file is included from?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, include, g++

How can I tell where g++ was able to find an include file?  Basically if I

```
#include <foo.h>
```

g++ will scan the search path, using any include options to add or alter the path.  But, at the end of days, is there a way I can tell the absolute path of foo.h that g++ chose to compile?  Especially relevant if there is more than one foo.h in the myriad of search paths.

Short of a way of accomplishing that... is there a way to get g++ to tell me what its final search path is after including defaults and all include options?

Comment: Related: is there any way to tell which parent include file(s) a child include file was included from? I.e. to show the included-from graph  (Hint: gcc -E isn't quite there...  might be processed to yield it.)

Answer (score 94, accepted):

This will give make dependencies which list absolute paths of include files:

```
gcc  -M showtime.c
```

If you don't want the system includes (i.e. `#include <something.h>`) then use:

```
gcc  -MM showtime.c
```

Comment: It should be noted that if you use in conjunction with "-o myObj.o", the output, not the compiled binary, goes into "myObj.o".  -M has an implicit -E, so the compilation is not peformed.  I found -MD is a very useful option instead, it performs the compile and puts the output in myObj.d instead.  Making a suitable param for just prepending to your compile line without strange effects like *.o now contains the output instead of the binary.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: All related gcc options are described [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Using_the_GNU_Compiler_Collection/preprocessor-options.html).

Answer (score 161):

```
g++ -H ...
```

will also print the full path of include files in a format which shows which header includes which

Comment: This seems to be more helpful than -M in my experience.  I like the hierarchical display of what includes what.

Comment: This is the best answer. You can add it to your build process without changing anything else.

Comment: This really answers the question more than the accepted answer.  Only unfortunate problem is that I couldn't get it to stop Clang from trying to compile the file normally, so I ended up using `clang++ -MM -H` (which is a slightly useful combination).

Comment: @rookie1024 Use `clang++ -H -fsyntax-only ...` if you would like to avoid generating output files (works for `gcc` too).

Comment: This looks like the counterpart of `/showIncludes` in MSVC.

Comment: With Clang, you can also get repeated includes with `-H -fshow-skipped-includes`.

Answer (score 13):

Sure use

```
g++ -E -dI  ... (whatever the original command arguments were)
```

Comment: There are several benefits to this solution: 1. You can discover multiple inclusions of a single header file (-H and -M print each included file only once) 2. You can see where it is included (name and line number of the original include instruction). 3. Thereby you can reliably(!) distinguish whether a header is included directly or indirectly or both (This is important for cleanups.)

Comment: @hagello Unfortunately with `-E -dI`, GCC only gives you the raw source line of the include if the header was already included - not the annotation with the resolved full path. For manual analysis this may be enough. But for automated analysis it makes things awkward.

Answer (score 7):

If you use `-MM` or one of the related options (`-M`, etc), you get just the list of headers that are included without having all the other preprocessor output (which you seem to get with the suggested `g++ -E -dI` solution).

You can also use the `-H` option.  It prints the headers as they are included with one dot `.` as a prefix for each level of nesting in the headers.  What you include directly is prefixed by a dot and a space; files that those files include are prefixed with two dots and a space, and so on.  This can be helpful.  The output appears on `stderr` rather than `stdout`.  (See also the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18593344/15168), which suggests `-H` but doesn't include information about the format of the output.)

Comment: `g++ -MM t.cc` shows no inclusion at all, just `t.o: t.cc`.  Does it need something else?

Comment: Nice - for completeness, you can get similar with MSVC using the `/showIncludes` option.  MSVC will even indent to show you the nesting of headers (I dont see that with `-M` on GCC).

Answer (score 7):

If your build process is very complicated...

```
constexpr static auto iWillBreak = 
#include "where/the/heck/is/this/file.h"
```

This will (almost certainly) cause a compilation error near the top of the file in question.  That should show you a compiler error with the path the compiler sees.

Obviously this is worse than the other answers, but sometimes this kind of hack is useful.

Comment: I find this very useful, especially as it works across different compilers and is directed towards the file I want.

Answer (score 1):

For MSVC you can use the `/showIncludes` option, which will display the files that are included.

---

*(This was stated in a comment of Michael Burr on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5834956/3907364) but I wanted to make it more visible and therefore added it as a separate answer.)*

---

Usability note: The compiler will emit this information to the standard error output which seems to be suppressed by default when using the windows command prompt. Use `2>&1` to redirect stderr to stdout to see it nonetheless.