# Tool to figure out how a header file is eventually being included

Tags: c++, c, eclipse

I am using C/C++ Eclipse. Is there an option in the IDE or an external tool to figure out the chain as to how a header file is eventually being included?

Comment: MSVS has an option that does just that.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Clarify?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I know MSVS has that option, but I'm using Eclipse

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834778/g-how-to-tell-where-a-header-file-is-included-from

Comment: @Iceman MSVC counts as an "external tool", doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative would be to remove such header and try to build your project. Your compiler will (likely) show you the include chain.

Comment: I was able to back chain using this technique

Answer (score 2):

You could just put an `#error` in the header file, the compiler should give you a trace like:

```
In file included from someheader.h:1:0,
                 from myheader.h:1,
                 from mysourcefile.c:1:
header_im_tracing.h:1:2: error: #error foobar
```

Comment: No it didn't show the complete chain.. only the header file and the parent source file.

Comment: That depends on your compiler (not your IDE), on MinGW it does. Oh well :]