# Why do some code files use close() without including unistd.h?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

Take this example: 
http://codebase.eu/tutorial/linux-socket-programming-c and
http://codebase.eu/tutorial/linux-socket-programming-c/code/tcpclient.cpp

Basically the first example app uses close() but does not include unistd.h. Some people mention this in the comments. It works for some without it and others have to include it.

My question is why is this: Why is it sometimes not necessary? Is it better to include it always? What does it mean when it is not necessary to include it?

Comment: It is always necessary to include the file that contains the declaration of a function that you're going to use. Another included file *might* include this as well, but you mustn't count on it. Also, it may work because of automatically generated declarations by the compiler - a function that is not declared explicitly is automatically assumed by the compiler to have a prototype of `int fun(...)` - which breaks miserably if your original function returns a pointer and you're on a platform where `sizeof(void*) != sizeof(int)`.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar That automatic assumption is C only, C++ does not do that.

Comment: Ah, yes, of course. I didn't see the `c++` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always better to `#include <unistd.h>` when using `int close(int);` because this is the only way to guarantee that a declaration of `int close(int);` will be available for your source code when compiling on POSIX platforms. In some cases other included files (or your buildchain) might include `unistd.h` or include a forward declaration for it.

When the C++ preprocessor processes your source code, it basically replaces your `#include <something.h>` line with the preprocessed contents of `something.h`. Hence if `something.h` (or recursively one of its included headers) has a `#include <unistd.h>` line then your source code will see the declaration of `int close(int);` even thou you didn't directly include the `unistd.h` header.

However, to ensure portability, always include `unistd.h` if you use the `int close(int);` function (`man 3p close`)!

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834778/g-how-to-tell-where-a-header-file-is-included-from) if you want to find out where a header file might be included from. Similarly you can use the `-E` flag for `g++`/`clang++` to output a fully preprocessed version of your source code to find out where the declaration of `int close(int);` comes from.

Comment: This answer is misleading: including a POSIX standard library header does *not* guarantee that all functions declared in that header become available. POSIX also requires macros (for which there are multiple options) to be defined before the first of the standard library headers is included. As a simple example, `dprintf` doesn't always become declared by simply including `<stdio.h>`, because ISO C++ doesn't allow it to be declared in that case, so implementations are required to *not* declare it in ISO C++-conforming modes, unless the required POSIX macros are defined too.

Comment: @hvd Can you please post a reference and an example of this please?

Comment: I don't have a concrete example where including `<unistd.h>` without the proper macro definitions fails to declare `close()`, but I do have a reference: it's stated in SUSv4, under "The `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` Feature Test Macro": "A POSIX-conforming application shall ensure that the feature test macro `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` is defined before inclusion of any header." And similarly below for `_XOPEN_SOURCE`. (Earlier standards used a different name.) It doesn't make any exception that suggests it may be omitted for some specific headers.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I am marking this as the answer since it and it's comments clarifies the question best.

Answer (score 2):

The referenced code uses `<iostream>`. It is likely, that `unistd.h` gets included because of it. But you should not count on it and include `unistd.h` yourself if you want to use `close()`.