# C Pre-Processor include-path order

Tags: c, linux, gcc, include-path

I typed "cpp -v" on linux and it resulted:

```
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
```

So I searched in that order for stdio.h, like the CPP would do, and I firstly found it at "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu".
Specifically, its full path is "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio.h"

BUT when I opened the file, it clearly states on 21-23 lines:

```
#ifndef _STDIO_H
# error "Never include <bits/stdio.h> directly; use <stdio.h> instead."
#endif
```

So, in theory when I type in my C source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

The pre-processor finds it at "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio.h", and includes it.
How is that possible? Is there a mechanism that makes the CPP ignore the "./bits/stdio.h"? Or is my theory wrong?

//I work on Ubuntu 18, I have also clang installed (don't know if it matters)

Comment: `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/` is not in the list of the search paths. To include that file one would need to do `#include <bits/stdio.h>`

Comment: You could find the actual header being included by looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834778/how-to-tell-where-a-header-file-is-included-from)

Comment: You can use `gcc -H …` to see the headers actually included by a compilation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it does not find `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio.h`.

Include directories are not searched recursively.

Based on the output from your question GCC will search for `#include<stdio.h>` with the following paths

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include/stdio.h
/usr/local/include/stdio.h
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include-fixed/stdio.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/stdio.h
/usr/include/stdio.h
```

in that order. Nothing more.

Since `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/stdio.h` doesn't exist, it can't be used.

Only (most likely) when looking for `/usr/include/stdio.h`, it will find a file and use that.

---

This is also what the error message you are referring to indicates. If you did `#include<bits/stdio.h>`, it would look for `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio.h` and use it. The error message is there to make sure that a user will not able to use such an include, because that file is an implementation detail of the standard library that should not be used by user code.

Comment: Yes that's it, thank you! I didn't know that the CPP doesn't search recursively.