# how to get the actually libraries filepath in compile in gcc?

Tags: c

I want to get the libraries paths of system installed libpcap with gcc, so I can copy it to another machine to cross compile my program that use libpcap.

Answer (score 1):

write an empty c source file into /tmp/1.c

```
int main(){}
```

run the command line

```
gcc -Wl,-t -lpcap /tmp/1.c
```

You will see a line looks like following in ubuntu 2004

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcap.so
```

or a line looks like following in mac os

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/lib/libpcap.tbd
```

Ps1, when you use libpcap-dev in ubuntu 2004, you need two kind of files to make the compile works:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcap.so
/usr/include/pcap.h
```

Ps2, if you want to know where the .h file is location, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/18593344/1586797