# Compiling OTPclient, implicit declaration of function ‘zbar_fourcc’

Tags: c, linux, gcc, cmake

On 'manual' compilation (ie. mkdir build; cmake ..), I get the following:

```
[ 25%] Building C object CMakeFiles/OTPClient.dir/src/parse-data.c.o
[ 27%] Building C object CMakeFiles/OTPClient.dir/src/parse-uri.c.o
[ 29%] Building C object CMakeFiles/OTPClient.dir/src/password-cb.c.o
[ 30%] Building C object CMakeFiles/OTPClient.dir/src/qrcode-parser.c.o
/tmp/SBo/OTPClient-master/src/qrcode-parser.c: In function ‘parse_qrcode’:
/tmp/SBo/OTPClient-master/src/qrcode-parser.c:36:35: error: implicit declaration of function ‘zbar_fourcc’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   36 |     zbar_image_set_format (image, zbar_fourcc ('Y','8','0','0'));
      |                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/OTPClient.dir/build.make:328: CMakeFiles/OTPClient.dir/src/qrcode-parser.c.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:85: CMakeFiles/OTPClient.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:136: all] Error 2
```

Checking:

- `zbar.h` *is* in `/usr/lib64`, and its subdirectory zbar is there too
- and it contains the zbar_fourcc function definition.
- $ `pkg-config --cflags --libs zbar` returns `-lzbar` (see compile command below)
- `zbar` is version 0.23.90
- `cmake` version 3.25.1
- `gcc (GCC)` 12.2.0
- I use Slackware64 15.0
- The failing compilation in `src/qrcode-parser.c` does contain an
  `#include <zbar.h>` statement

Compiling with VERBOSE=1, produces the compile command (formatting is mine):

```
/usr/bin/cc 
   -DGETTEXT_PACKAGE=\"OTPClient\" 
   -I/usr/local/src/internet/opt/OTPClient-master/build 
   -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 
   -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 
   -I/usr/include/at-spi-2.0 
   -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 
   -I/usr/lib64/dbus-1.0/include 
   -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0 
   -I/usr/include/cairo 
   -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 
   -I/usr/include/harfbuzz 
   -I/usr/include/fribidi 
   -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 
   -I/usr/include/pixman-1 
   -I/usr/include/libxml2 
   -I/usr/include/freetype2 
   -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 
   -I/usr/include/libpng16 
   -I/usr/include/libmount 
   -I/usr/include/blkid 
   -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 
   -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include 
   -I/usr/include/uuid 
   -I/usr/include/libsecret-1 
   -Wall 
   -Wextra -O2 -Wformat=2 -Wmissing-format-attribute -fstack-protector-strong -Wundef 
   -Wmissing-format-attribute -fdiagnostics-color=always -Wstrict-prototypes -Wunreachable-code 
   -Wchar-subscripts -Wwrite-strings -Wpointer-arith -Wbad-function-cast -Wcast-align 
   -Werror=format-security -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Wno-sign-compare 
   -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -pie -fPIE -DBUILD_GUI -DBUILD_CLI -std=gnu11 
   -MD -MT CMakeFiles/OTPClient.dir/src/qrcode-parser.c.o -MF 
   CMakeFiles/OTPClient.dir/src/qrcode-parser.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/OTPClient.dir/src/qrcode-parser.c.o 
   -c /usr/local/src/internet/opt/OTPClient-master/src/qrcode-parser.c
```

I rarely use CMAKE, but it seems strange to me that the command does not include a
`-I/usr/include/zbar.h` statement.

Any takers?

Comment: "`zbar.h` *is* in `/usr/lib64`" - No, a **header** file is not located in the directory intended for **libraries**. It is most likely located somewhere under `/usr/include`. It could be that some of other include directories contain `zbar.h` file, so it is included instead of the standard one. See [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834778/how-to-tell-where-a-header-file-is-included-from) for debug, which exact header has been included by the compiler.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typing error. Of course it's in `/usr/include`, as is the zbar directory containing the parts. But, as you said, I did find a old copy (2014) of `zbar.h` in `usr/local/include`! Strangely enough, there is no zbar.pc in `/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig/` I deleted `zbar.h` and now compilation succeeded. Thanks!