# Not able to locate a header file

Tags: c++, header-files, icc

I am not able to locate a particular header file on disk, while my compiler (icpc) includes it without any errors.

**How can I find the header file?**

I tried querying the preprocessor for the header file locations as suggested [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344317/where-does-gcc-look-for-c-and-c-header-files).

First of all, icpc does not report its preprocessor. Secondly, I cannot find the header file in `cc1`'s locations as well.

Comment: If you're using an IDE, most of them have an option to open an included file if you right click on the file name in the `#include` statement. Once the file is open, you should be able to hover over the file tab, or use the File -> Save As option, to figure out the file path.

Comment: Maybe they're not on the disk :-) The standard doesn't actually mandate that. They could be hardcoded into the compiler, extracted from an HTTP transaction to Intel's web site, even stored on Voyager 1 and you have to go through NASA to compile your code (a rather slow process, due to the 32-hour lead time (out and back) for getting the header file back from eighteen billion kilometers away).

Comment: I never though aliens wound need to know that char is one byte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in your compiler for and option, similar to /P in MSVC:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z9z0bx6(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Yes,  `-P` and `-E` options are there. But they do not report *where* the file was found.

Comment: I remember MSVC can show these names, I cannot find this key. Study the keys of your compiler.

Comment: For gcc I'm pretty sure the preprocessed file contains the full path name in `# ...` lines. For gcc you can also have a look at the output produced with the `-M` option: this creates dependencies suitable for `make` and definitely includes the information to locate the file, although possibly relative to the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can find it in the path you installed your compiler, say if you installed mingw at `C:\MingW`, then the include files will be at `C:\MinGW\include` so go and search the path you installed icpc will help I think:)

Comment: No, they are being used from a remote location through a complex expansion of environment variables.

Comment: Well, if I am facing this problem, I'll probably use Everything to find it. http://www.voidtools.com/download.php