# How to Place non-Default C++ Packages in Cygwin File Structure Correctly

Tags: c++, c, include, cygwin

I'm a bit of a novice at C++ development.  The goal is to download an correctly ready a new package so that Cygwin will understand the statement #include "pcap.h".  The directions for the developer package for WinpCap were pretty straight forward:

1. Download the ZIP archive containing the developer's pack
2. Uncompress it to the desired folder

[Developer Package Instructions Link](https://www.winpcap.org/devel.htm)

The part that I am having trouble with is the "desired folder" part.  I found the path for where Cygwin is storing default libraries which for me is C:Cygwin64/usr/include .  I placed the package in this directory but that didn't work.  pcap.h is nested in the unzipped folders two or three directories in.  I noticed that this is a little different when compared to the directories that were there by default. 
 To test whether or not this was correct or not I simply did an `#include "pcap.h"` statement in a .cpp file that previously compiled with no issues.  With the new included statement I got a

> fatal error: pcap.h: No such file or directory
>   from Cygwin.

How should I go about solving this?  The goal is to have this behave like any other directory one would want.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344317/where-does-gcc-look-for-c-and-c-header-files) to find where `gcc` searches for the header files.

```
`gcc -print-prog-name=cc1plus` -v
```

The result of the command in a Cygwin console :

```
$ `gcc -print-prog-name=cc1plus` -v
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:    
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/i686-pc-cygwin
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include/c++/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/include-fixed
 /usr/include
End of search list.
```

You could still maybe place your package's headers in one of them.